# Find and extract data from Excel sheet and paste it into related columns using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I have the following objective:

1. Loop through a huge excel sheet (200,000+ rows)
2. Find some data based on matching parameters  (the original file is an xml file, so structured data... but I am using a Mac, where the XML parser is not supported)
3. Copy the data between double quote related to each variable
4. Paste the value in the relative column

Additional constraints I have to face:

- Every value to copy is between double quotes (this is "good news", helping me to identify the right data to copy and paste)
- Imagine the txt. data as a list of data objects (=> it's sequence of purchases, with related info, made by customers). The macro should be able to loop through the list and copy paste the data, starting a new row every time a new ID purchase comes up. Good news is that every purchase is marked by a unique ID.

I’m providing below an example of input and output. I would really be grateful if someone could help me on this.

```
//INPUT

<SequenceNumber="1">
 <PurchaseSegment DayDateTime="2020-02-29T06:45:00" ArrivalDateTime="2020-02-29T09:40:00" StopQuantity="0" PurchaseNumber="229" ElapsedTime="115">"
 <DayPoS LocationCode="AAA" DockID="4" />"                                 
 <ArrivalPoS LocationCode="CCC" />"
</SequenceNumber>

<SequenceNumber="2">
 <PurchaseSegment DayDateTime="2019-09-28T06:41:00" ArrivalDateTime="2020-02-29T09:40:00" StopQuantity="1" PurchaseNumber="123" ElapsedTime="115">"
 <DayPoS LocationCode="AAA" DockID="3" />"
 <ArrivalPoS LocationCode="QQC" />"
</SequenceNumber>
```

//EXPECTED OUTPUT (by running the VBA macro)
[image]

Here you can find also my VBA attempt, I leveraged some VBA code I already found, but didn't succeed.

```
Public Sub TextDataToColumn() 
Dim val As Variant val = "PurchaseSegment DayDateTime" // it would be great to have a list of paramaters here...
Set c = Cells.Find(val, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False) 
If Not c Is Nothing Then 
Do 
MsgBox "Value of val is found at " & c.Address & vbCrLf & c.Offset(0, 1).Value & vbCrLf & c.Offset(0, 2).Value 
 Set c = Cells.FindNext(c) 
 Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstaddress 
 End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the result of that VBA code?

Comment: Hi @JSR. It shows me a popup saying the "Value of val is found at at cell A2" .. and in cell "A7". I understand this code is correctly identifying the cell in which the parameter is placed, but it is not helping me in analysing the content of that cell (I could have more than one parameter and the relative value in one cell) and in extracting the value i'm looking for. Would you have any suggestion on how to perform this task? Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using Text to Columns with "=" as delimiter? It wouldn't get you all the way there but would get you part of the way. Or regular expressions. Or if the text entries are always the same length you could use formulas - MID, FIND etc.

Comment: Imagine this as a long xml file (200,000+ rows), which i converted into a .txt file (because Mac does not offer the same XML parser capabilities as Windows). Text entries unfortunately won't be the same length, so I could try regular expression... even though I'm very new to them.. would you have any suggestion on how to capture only the data between double quotes using regular expression?

Comment: How about using `Find` and looking for the double quotes?

Comment: When I put your text into an xml validator, it shows as not valid xml.  Does VBA for the MAC have the dictionary object and class objects?

Comment: Hi @Ron Rosenfeld. Unfortunately not.. I had found an incredibly useful snippet here (https://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-read-data-from-xml-file/), but unfortunately VBA for MAC does not have the dictionary object and class objects (and it is also missing ActiveX). For this reason I switched to .txt, rather than using XML Parse functions

Comment: @JSR. I could give it a try, but my fear is the following. Given a string in one cell like this one  `<PurchaseSegment DayDateTime="2020-02-29T06:45:00" ArrivalDateTime="2020-02-29T09:40:00" StopQuantity="0" PurchaseNumber="229" ElapsedTime="115">` , will `Find` be able to run inside the string and select each parameter and value or will it stop at the first one only?

Comment: Does it have the Collection object?

Comment: `<SequenceNumber="1">` this isn't valid....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your text using VBA text functions.

As I mentioned in my comments, what you posted is **NOT** a valid XML document.

I adapted what I would have done using a Dictionary and Classes, to using a Collection and Array. (Although there is a Mac add-in to enable use of dictionary object).

After pre-processing the text lines to make it easier to parse, we loop through all the text lines and store the appropriate items in defined locations in the array.

We collect each row of item into the collection object, and then output them onto a worksheet.

It works for the sample data you posted, but if your data is, in addition to being invalid xml, also has irregularities in the naming and formatting of the different nodes, you'll need a more sophisticated parsing method.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub splitSeq()
    Dim cS As Collection
    Dim WB As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant

    Dim I As Long, v, w, x

'Set workbook, worksheet and range parameters
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
With WB
    Set wsSrc = .Worksheets("Sheet4") 'or wherever the data exists

    On Error Resume Next 'add a sheet if not present
    Set wsRes = Worksheets("Results")
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 9 'need to add a sheet
            Set wsRes = WB.Worksheets.Add
            wsRes.Name = "Results"
        Case Is <> 0 'Something else went wrong
            MsgBox "Error number " & Err.Number & vbLf & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    End Select
End With

'set results range
Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'read data into array for processing speed
'assuming all data is in column A
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

'loop through data and save the Sequence objects
'Each starts with <sequence and ends with </sequence

Set cS = New Collection

For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    If vSrc(I, 1) Like "<Sequence*" Then
        ReDim vRes(1 To 8) 're-initialize array
    Else
            'Remove confusing spaces in node names and <> in attributes
                vSrc(I, 1) = Replace(vSrc(I, 1), "Segment DayDate", "SegmentDayDate")
                vSrc(I, 1) = Replace(vSrc(I, 1), "Pos Location", "PosLocation")
                vSrc(I, 1) = Replace(vSrc(I, 1), "<", "")
                vSrc(I, 1) = Replace(vSrc(I, 1), ">""", "")
                vSrc(I, 1) = Replace(vSrc(I, 1), ">", "")

            v = Split(vSrc(I, 1))
            For Each w In v
                x = Split(w, "=")

                'Remove leading and trailing double quotes
                    If Left(x(1), 1) = """" And Right(x(1), 1) = """" Then
                        x(1) = Mid(x(1), 2)
                        x(1) = Left(x(1), Len(x(1)) - 1)
                    End If

                Select Case x(0)
                    Case "PurchaseSegmentDayDateTime"
                        vRes(1) = x(1)
                    Case "ArrivalDateTime"
                        vRes(2) = x(1)
                    Case "StopQuantity"
                        vRes(3) = x(1)
                    Case "PurchaseNumber"
                        vRes(4) = x(1)
                    Case "ElapsedTime"
                        vRes(5) = x(1)
                    Case "DayPosLocationCode"
                        vRes(6) = x(1)
                    Case "ArrivalPosLocationCode"
                        vRes(8) = x(1)
                    Case "DockID"
                        vRes(7) = x(1)
                    Case "/SequenceNumber"
                        cS.Add vRes
                End Select
            Next w
        End If
    Next I

'set up results array
ReDim vRes(0 To cS.Count, 1 To 8)

'Headers
    vRes(0, 1) = "PurchaseSegment DayDateTime"
    vRes(0, 2) = "ArrivalDateTime"
    vRes(0, 3) = "StopQuantity"
    vRes(0, 4) = "PurchaseNumber"
    vRes(0, 5) = "ElapsedTime"
    vRes(0, 6) = "DayPoS LocationCode"
    vRes(0, 7) = "DockID"
    vRes(0, 8) = "ArrivalPoS LocationCode"

'fill in the data
I = 0
For Each v In cS
    I = I + 1
    With v
        vRes(I, 1) = v(1)
        vRes(I, 2) = v(2)
        vRes(I, 3) = v(3)
        vRes(I, 4) = v(4)
        vRes(I, 5) = v(5)
        vRes(I, 6) = v(6)
        vRes(I, 7) = v(7)
        vRes(I, 8) = v(8)
    End With
Next v

'Set Results range
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))

'Write and format results
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value2 = vRes
    .Style = "Output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried to use it, but when I run it, a popup comes up saying "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user3926863 At what line did the macro stop when you saw that?

Comment: It stops here: 

With WB
   Set wsSrc = .Worksheets("Sheet4") 'or wherever the data exists

Comment: @user3926863 And does your data exist on `Sheet4`?  Do you have a `Sheet4` in your workbook?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was over-excited by the code you wrote and noticed it only when I wrote it in the comments. I replaced Sheet4 with Sheet1 and it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204509/discussion-between-user3926863-and-ron-rosenfeld).